# Error on window open?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, 3d, lwjgl

When I make a simple window it gives me an error and I have no idea why! I am on Linux Mint 64 bit. (Dell Inspiron 1764)

Here's the error:

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7f81187c9a20 serial: 93 error: GLXBadFBConfig request_code: 156 minor_code: 34
at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:321)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.create(LinuxContextImplementation.java:51)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.<init>(ContextGL.java:132)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:797)
at renderEngine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:27)
at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:10)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine close requested state of uncreated window
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.isCloseRequested(Display.java:549)
at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:14)
```

Here's my code:

```
package engineTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import renderEngine.DisplayManager;

public class MainGameLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayManager.createDisplay();

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            //game logic
            //render
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
        }

        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
    }

}
```

And then the other class is:

```
package renderEngine;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;  
import org.lwjgl.test.applet.OpenGL;

public class DisplayManager {

private static final int WIDTH = 1000;

private static final int HEIGHT = 700;

private static final int FPS_CAP = 120;

public static void createDisplay() {

    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2);
        attribs.withForwardCompatible(true);
        attribs.withProfileCore(true);

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
            OpenGL opengl = new OpenGL();
            GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void updateDisplay() {
        Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
        Display.update();
    }

    public static void closeDisplay() {

        Display.destroy();

    }

}
```

Comment: Try googling "GLXBadFBConfig", there's explainations. ex: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/183084-X-Error-of-failed-request-GLXBadFBConfig

Comment: I looked at the article, but they have no ideas on how to fix it! :(

Comment: is 3.2 context available on your linux? display mode should maybe be one of the predefined Available resolutions for your hardware, not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much work at this, I finally decided to read Minecraft's source code and see how they created their OpenGL window. I put it in my code, and now the window opens perfectly!

To get it working if you have the problem, replace

> Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);

with

> Display.create(new PixelFormat().withDepthBits(24));